# Why these statements give lexical error (not syntax error)?

Tags: compiler-construction

In my Compiler Design course, my professor told that these statements should generate error when analyzed by Lexical Analyzer.

Not writing operator after cout:

```
cout "Hello";
```

Not writing any status-code after 'return' in int main():

```
int main(){
...
return ;
}
```

And some more examples like this.

According to me this is not the duty of lexical analyzer. It simply finds the tokens in code, and generate an error only if there is an invalid token. As in the examples above all the tokens are valid, Lexical Analyzer should not give any error. (Instead Syntax Analyzer will)
Is my thinking correct or am I missing something?

Comment: indeed, that's not an error that a lexer would raise (IMHO)

Comment: This seems like a question you should address to your professor, or the teaching assistant for the class, or whatever you have at your college. Perhaps you misunderstood; otherwise, you are correct that it is a very idiosyncratic definition of "lexical error".

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not one we can answer on Stack Overflow.